# Chrome extension that turns on/off mobile profile

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there an extension that will allow me to turn the profile of a running Chrome window from desktop to mobile? This is, so that it automatically renders pages in mobile layout then I switch the profile on, and back to desktop profile when I switch it off.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this built in feature https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this extension it allows to switch the user-agent: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

Regards